# Is it possible to merge cells&center of pivot table columns OBIEE 12c like in Excel?

Tags: excel, oracle, pivot-table, oracle12c, obiee

We have the following criteria:

[image]

Results:

[image]

Our requirement was to merge '01057 Total' and '01057' columns into one column with leaving only '01057' as column label. Since there is no explicit way to do this, we just tried to remove letters from '01057 Total' and used custom css to remove left and right borders from these two columns;

```
border-left: 0px solid;
border-right: 0px solid;
```

As a result, we got the following:
[image]

It looks like merged while browsing through BI , but when exported to Excel, borders are present and these two columns are separated again:
[image]

I was wondering if there is any other way or if it is even possible to do this. It might seem like the requirement shouldn't be done in OBIEE, but somehow it makes sense to have this functionality in pivot tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't because that's simply not how the tool works. Excel is Excel. Analytics is Analytics. The whole grid is rendered dynamically and especially the totals are special cell types.

Comment: Thanks, Chris! Sometimes its hard to explain users that excel and BI are completely different tools.

Comment: For the same reason that a bunch of ingrdients aren't the same thing as a 3-star menu.